# Rails sort_by method if value is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've got a method that I'm using to sort by the result instead of a database column at the moment which works nicely. It will return from the below each loop with a value against each record, then sort the table based on these:

```
<% @records.sort_by(&:methodName).reverse.each do |record| %>
    <%= record.methodName %>
<% end %>
```

This works really well - however this method only gets used after a user interacts with the record itself. For instance like a rating, so a record will begin life without a rating, then ratings will be submitted after this point.

It works nicely, until you create a new record that doesn't have a value for this to sort by - is there a way of saying "Sort by what this method returns, if the record doesn't have a value for this, put it at the bottom"?

At the moment I get an exception because it's not a number 'NaN'...because it's empty :(

As always - any help massively appreciated for a Rails beginner here..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<% @records.sort_by{|r| r.try(:methodName)}.reverse.each do |record| %>
```

Edit:

```
<% @records.sort_by{|r| r.methodName.nan? ? 10000 : r.methodName}.reverse.each do |record| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude - still getting the same thing though 'NaN'

Comment: Updated the answer with a different technique. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same result mate :( - Awesome try though, I should have thought of checking and turning it into a number if it was NaN

Comment: Does your methodName return NaN or 0 if it isn't filled?

Comment: That's an incredibly good point - simple if statement within the method to check is something exists, otherwise return 0. Thanks very much for putting up with my slip of mind there! Your answers were great mate

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `methodName` always exists (as a method) and returns a Numeric when the value exists and `nil` or `false` otherwise:

```
@records.sort_by{ |r| r.methodName || -9999999 }
```

That will cause all records with no entry to be at the start of the list before the `reverse`, and at the end of the list afterwards.

If that doesn't work, please state what `methodName` returns for the new records.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
newrs, oldrs = @records.partition{ |r| r.methodName }
newrs.each do |r| ... records that have a value for methodName ... end
oldrs.each do |r| ... records with no value for methodName ... end
```

Comment: Thank you mate - Sorted it now by checking if the a value exists and is given to the method, otherwise returning 0 :)

Comment: great idea on the partition. Didn't even know that method existed in Ruby.

Comment: @Nuby, It's part of Ruby's [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) module, which is full of nice goodies for dealing with collections like Arrays, Hashes, etc.

Comment: I never realized how many awesome time-savers are in Ruby. Every time I write more than 3 lines of code, I start searching the RDoc to see if it's already a standard method...